# why does the test[unitTest] has a module icon if its not?

Tags: android-studio, module

It got me really confusing that the "test[unitTest]" has an icon of gray directory and blue rectangle, which is the module icon, whereas it is not a module.

This is what I mean:

[image]

so why is it there, maybe it is some type of module?

Comment: I would really appreciate your answers